# How do i configure nginx to use part of a URL as a header?

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, http-headers

I am trying to get a server application running which supports multiple customers.

They should each access the app with their own URL, e.g. `http://localhost:8082/customer1/config`, but the application needs to have the customer specific part as a request header instead. The request should be redirected to `http://localhost:9002/config`.

I can achieve this if i write a location rule for each customer:

```
server {
    listen          8082;
    server_name     localhost;
    root            /;

    location /customer1/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
            proxy_set_header X-customer customer1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002/;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

How can i configure nginx so it takes any customer name and puts it into the header?

Comment: You can't fix the application? This sort of logic really belongs there.

Comment: I would have preferred the application to take care of that, but unfortunately, i have no control over that part.

Comment: How exactly do the app developers expect this to work, then? What did they say for themselves when you asked them about this?

Comment: They expect this to be done the way i am trying to it here: By putting the customer in the request header.

Comment: You need to push back more. Incompetent developers are no excuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i made this work:

```
location ~ ^/(?!vaadinServlet|customer)(.+?)/(.*) {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
       proxy_set_header X-customer $1;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002/$2;
       proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Thanks to Tim for the inspiration.

Note that this also prevents URLs starting with `vaadinServlet` or `customer` from being selected.
If you don't need special treatment for such keywords, it would suffice to use

```
location ~ ^/(.+?)/(.*) {
    ...
}
```

If the URL part to be handled doesn't have to appear at the start (i.e. after the server name), remove the `^`.

Answer (score 3):

This might be possible with a regular expression that has a capture group, combined with mod_headers which you would have to [compile into Nginx](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx).

If the rule works, it could look something like this - note that I haven't gone to any effort to write the correct regular expression, you'll have to do that, and it's completely untested. This is meant simply to give you the concept so you can follow it up and work out the details, or maybe rule it out.

```
location ~ /(customer?)/config {
  add_header X-customer $1;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9002/config;
  # proxy_pass related declarations
}
```

If it works I suggest posting what you final location is to help others who may have this need in future.